# Mirroring a checkbox and select when weither are selected or clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, checkbox

I have a `select` and a `checkbox` that I want to work in tandem.  The `select` has four options with values *null*, *Yes*, *No*, and *Maybe*.

When the `select` is either *Yes* or *Maybe*, the `checkbox` should be **checked**.

When the `checkbox` is **unchecked** and the `select` should be set back to *null* and the `.text()` set as an empty string.

Everything seems to work except I'm losing the text for the options in the `select` when I uncheck the `checkbox`.  When I check the options, the selected `.text()` is empty, and the selected `.prop("null")` is set to *Yes* which is now blank.

The snippet shows what's happening.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#test-1").blur(function() {
        if($("#test-1").val() == "Yes" || $("#test-1").val() == "Maybe" ) {
            $("#result").html("<p>The SELECT is 'YES' and the CHECKBOX is checked. This is intended.<br>Now uncheck CHECKBOX<p>");
            $("#test-2").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("#result").html("<p>The SELECT is 'NO' and the CHECKBOX is unchecked<br>Now SELECT 'YES'<p>");        
            //$("#test-1").text("");
            $("#test-1").prop("null");
            $("#test-2").prop("checked", false);
        } 
    });
});

$(function() {
    $("#test-2").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#result").html("Hello World 3")
            $("#test-1 option:selected").text("Yes");
            $("#test-1 option:selected").prop("Yes");
        } else {
            $("#result").html("<p>The CHECKBOX is unchecked and the SELECT is empty, but some SELECT options are missing. Check SELECT.<p>")
            $("#test-1 option:selected").text("");
            $("#test-1 option:selected").prop("null");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.test {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    line-height: 22px;
}
#test-2 {
    border: 12px solid red;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#result {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select <span style="font-weight:600;color:red">YES</span>. Click outside to lose focus.</p>
<div class="test">
    <div>
        Test 1: 
        <select id="test-1" name="test-1">
            <option selected value="null"></option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <br>Test 2:
        <input id="test-2" type="checkbox" name="test-2">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="result">{results appear here}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of some unnecessary and harmful calls to jQuery methods.

These get the property named "null" of the select/selected option element, which essentially do nothing:

```js
$("#test-1").prop("null");
$("#test-1 option:selected").prop("Yes");
$("#test-1 option:selected").prop("null");
```

...whereas these change the text of the current selected option element. The second is the culprit we're looking for.

```js
$("#test-1 option:selected").text("Yes");
$("#test-1 option:selected").text("");
```

That being said, you can fix your code as follow:

```js
$select.change(function() {
  const currentValue = $select.val();
  
  // If the current selected option has a value of
  // either "Yes" or "Maybe", we check the checkbox.
  // Uncheck it otherwise.
  if (['Yes', 'Maybe'].includes(currentValue)) {
    $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  }
});

$checkbox.change(function() {
  if (!$checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    // If the checkbox, after being .change()-d, is unchecked,
    // find the option whose value="" is "null"
    // and select it.
    $select.find('[value="null"]').prop('selected', true);
  }
});
```

Also, it is unnecessary to have two `$(function() { /* ... */ })` in this case. Either use one, or skip it altogether.

Try it:

```js
const [$select, $checkbox] = [$('#select'), $('#checkbox')];

$select.change(function() {
  const currentValue = $select.val();
  
  if (['Yes', 'Maybe'].includes(currentValue)) {
    $checkbox.prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  }
});

$checkbox.change(function() {
  if (!$checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    $select.find('[value="null"]').prop('selected', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <div>
    Test 1:
    <select id="select">
      <option selected value="null"></option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
      <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br>Test 2:
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the code.  This worked.  I had to add the ```} else {``` to the ```$checkbox.change()```, because if you selected 'Yes' or 'Maybe' from the dropdown, and then unchecked the checkbox, the dropdown had to back to its original state.

```} else {
      $select.find('[value="Yes"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: It can be simplified to just `$checkbox.prop('checked', ['Yes', 'Maybe'].includes(currentValue));`.

Comment: @Unmitigated Yes, but that wouldn't be as readable and a bit harder to explain.